# Asp.Net configurar rotas de múltiplos projetos mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Para que eu possa entender como funciona essa arquitetura de múltiplos projetos MVC em uma Solution.

Como fazer a comunicação (um link) de um projeto para outro dentro de uma mesma solution?[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por exemplo, Gostaria que na View Home do Gerenciamento eu consiga um link para View Home Portaria.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Andei pesquisando mais não achei muitos conteúdos e os que achei estavam bem vagos.
Se puderem deixar um exemplo de configuração de rotas e outros, agradeço.

Comment: Acredito que isso não seja possível, mas existem especialistas em ASP.NET MVC... acho que você só consegue compartilhar a regra de negócios via DLL mesmo.

Comment: Talvez seu caso seja um problema [XY](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%c3%a9-o-problema-xy), o que está tentando resolver? acredito que no seu cenário usar [Areas](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dn877998.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) seja uma solução. Passar uma URL de outro site/sistema é simples, mas eles não irão compartilhar recursos, exemplo 1 `ViewBag`

Comment: Queremos justamente migrar de areas para projetos. o Portal cresceu muito e quando precisamos publicar algo em uma area, acabamos por parar todo o resto do portal. O é diferente quando se trabalha com multiplos projetos. Só publicamos aquele que sofre alteração.

Answer (score 0):

Rotas você utiliza quando está trabalhando com as Areas do MVC, ou seja, {url}/{area}/{controller}/{view}. Neste caso você tem mais de um projeto MVC e cada projeto pode ser uma aplicação ou um subaplicação no IIS.
Para uma aplicação acessar a outra você pode configurar o iis local para rodar as aplicações de forma independente, por exemplo:

- Gerenciamento - local.gerenciamento.com
- Portaria - local.portaria.com

Para uma aplicação acessar a outra você vai fazer esse apontamento através de links. Na aplicação portaria você vai ter links apontando para local.gerenciamento.com e vice-versa.
Essa solução pode gerar um problema de autenticação. Se você se autentica na aplicação de gerenciamento e tentar acessar alguma página da aplicação de portaria que requer autenticação você terá um acesso negado.
Este problema pode ser resolvido através de soluções como servidores de identidade (ex: Identity Server) ou através da configuração da machine key no IIS.
Avalie se essa separação é realmente necessária, pois, pode aumentar a complexidade do seu sistema. Se você está com problemas de publicar uma correção e surgir outra considere a utilização de testes unitários e de integração integrado com um processo de build automatizado.